# is it possible to treat a class object like a variable?

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

Is it possible to treat class object like a variable ???

What i know we can treat it like a function:

```
class hello{
    public function __invoke(){
        return ['one','two','three'];
    }
}

$obj = new hello;
var_export($obj()); //returns the defined array ['one','two','three']
```

What i need to do is to do it with out the ():
means treat it like a variable & make it return an (array or another object)

```
$obj = new hello;
var_export($obj); //returns the defined array ['one','two','three']
```

Is there any magic method like `__invoke()` to do this... or even a hacky way to do it ???

Comment: there's no "on read" magic method. so, no, just putting the object variable somewhere doesn't allow it to trigger code execution. the closets would be `__toString()`, but that HAS to return a string, so there's no way you could have a magic method return an array instead.

Comment: why do yo need this ? how would you use your instance ? maybe interface can help you

Comment: really need to know what you are trying to do, why you are trying to do it, and why you have restrictions on parenthesis...may help us give you a better idea of what can be done that isn't hacky within your specified requirements.  You could do something like `ServiceLocator::invoke('hello')`...but again, need to know more about why you are doing it to understand what would or wouldn't work.

Comment: @developerwjk can you explain with code ??? i don't understand...

Comment: in laravel there is a class called collection that can be used to return & iterate over an array of instances & do some function on the array... do any body how did thay did it ??? (sorry! i am a beginner & can't understand their code)

Comment: nevermind, now that I see an answer, I see I totally didn't get what you were trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do that because one can't extent built-in things like `array`. There are some ways to achieve parts of what you want though:

#### Printing out custom data on `var_dump()`

This is a feature was introduced in PHP 5.6 with the [`__debugInfo()` magic method](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo).

```
class Hello {
    public function __debugInfo(){
        return ['one','two','three'];
    }
}

var_dump(new Hello);
```

[This would output](http://3v4l.org/tg69G):

```
object(Hello)#1 (3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "three"
}
```

#### Acting like an array

While you can't make your objects *be* an array (that is, extend it), they can behave like arrays if you implement the [`ArrayAccess` interface](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php):

```
class Hello implements ArrayAccess {
    private $data = [];
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->data[$offset]);
    }
    /* insert the rest of the implementation here */
}
```

And then you can use it like an array:

```
$fake_array = new Hello();
$fake_array['foo'] = 'bar';
echo $fake_array['foo'];
```

Note that you can't pass classes that implement this interface into methods hinted with `array`.

---

It is not possible to act like any other primitive data type unfortunately. If you want ultimate flexibility, you will have to look at things like Python and Scala. In PHP you will need to use some pattern like a `getData()` and `setData()` interface for the wrapping object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Anonymous's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31843351/482256), along with `\ArrayAccess` it can be useful to implement `\IteratorAggregate` (to work with `foreach()`) and `\Countable` (to work with `count()`)

```
namespace {
    abstract class AEnumerable implements \IteratorAggregate, \Countable, \ArrayAccess {
        protected $_array;

        public function getIterator() {
            return new \ArrayIterator($this->_array);
        }
        public function count() {
            return count($this->_array);
        }
        public function offsetExists( $offset ) {
            return isset($this->_array[$offset]);
        }
        public function offsetGet( $offset ) {
            return $this->_array[$offset];
        }
        public function offsetSet( $offset, $value ) {
            $this->_array[$offset] = $value;
        }
        public function offsetUnset( $offset ) {
            unset( $this->_array[$offset] );
        }
    }
}
```